# Custom color scale for filled.contour heatmap with base R

Tags: r, heatmap, color-palette

I have this kind of color palette that I want to use

```
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue1",
                                "green", "yellow", "red", "darkred"))
```

Illustration how my graphs look at the moment
[image]

I have used `filled.contour()` to plot this graph with some modifications.

Here's a part of the code that makes somewhat similar graph

```
load("workspace.RData")
library(lubridate)

breaks <- "2 hours"
palette <- colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "blue", "lightblue1",
                              "green", "yellow", "red", "darkred"))
f <- function(x) as.POSIXct(levels(cut(x, breaks)))

filled.contour(x = data$Time,
               y = log10(channels),
               z = df,
               color.palette = palette,
               plot.axes = axis(1, at = f(data$Time),
                                labels = format(f(data$Time), "%H:%M")))
```

by using `data`, `channels` and `df` from [my workspace](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2kxzshea3k0nitr/AACnJmantk3LnlVpuQtQOPePa?dl=0) made with `save.image()`.

Now the function is making the color legend on the right look like that by default. I would like to specify myself that dark blue corresponds to 0 and dark red corresponds to some user defined value for example 20 million.

I want this because if I was to compare the graph of this data with graph of some other data, they would have exactly the same color legend.

Tell me if I need to provide more information or anything.

EDIT:

Provided the data from my workspace as [workspace.RData](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2kxzshea3k0nitr/AACnJmantk3LnlVpuQtQOPePa?dl=0) file.

Comment: More information would be useful, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It is difficult for someone to reproduce your example with this little code.

Comment: Still stuck here. Is there a way I can modify `filled.contour()` function to my liking?

Comment: Extracting your files returned an error for me. To make it more easy for people to actually answer your question, please provide sample data a specified in the link provided earlier, for example using dput().

Comment: Current file behind link is my workspace that holds df, data and channels. Is that okay? What kind of error are you getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`levels` (and `nlevels`) parameters seem to do the job just fine... I feel stupid.